# How can the propagator be written in the below integral form?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, dirac-delta-distributions, propagator

I’am finding it difficult to understand as to how the delta function is written as a product of many delta functions with the integral

[image: pic]

Comment: This is Bransden and Joachain's *Quantum Mechanics*. You should be able to use the properties of the Dirac delta to simplify (5.301) to (5.298), an equation on the previous page.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Can you convert the picture of the text into typed-out, formatted text? It makes the content index-able by search engines, and shows up better on different devices' displays. For formulae, try [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Hints: 1. The $N\!-\!1$ extra delta distributions in eq. (3.101) are cancelled by $N\!-\!1$ integrations. 2. Eq. (3.102) uses the BCH expansion for small $\Delta t$.